# Creating a wrapper around the Session object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm trying to create a SessionWrapper class which I can manage sessions in my MVC applications. For that I'm thinking the best way of doing so is by creating a wrapper class for HttpContext which would then allow me to access HttpContext.Current.Session.

**SessionState interface**

```
public interface ISessionState
{
    void Clear();
    void Delete(string key);
    object Get(string key);
    T Get<T>(string key) where T : class;
    ISessionState Store(string key, object value);
}
```

**SessionState class**

```
public class DefaultSessionState : ISessionState
{
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase _session;

    public DefaultSessionState(HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _session.RemoveAll();
    }

    public void Delete(string key)
    {
        _session.Remove(key);
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        return _session[key];
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        return _session[key] as T;
    }

    public ISessionState Store(string key, object value)
    {
        _session[key] = value;

        return this;
    }
}
```

**BaseController class**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISessionState _sessionState;

    protected BaseController(ISessionState sessionState)
    {
        _sessionState = sessionState;
    }

    internal protected ISessionState SessionState 
    { 
        get { return _sessionState; } 
    }
}
```

**Using the SessionState wrapper**

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    public UserController(ISessionState sessionState) : base(sessionState) { }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // clear the session and add some data
        SessionState.Clear();
        SessionState.Store("key", "some value");
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: For UserController, looks like you have the constructor with the name as "MyController".  Is that a typo or really like that in your code?  Also, their is no closing brace on your UserController constructor either.

Comment: its typo i will update that but I will never be able to get the run time error if I'm missing any closing or opening brace :)

Comment: That's what I figured, just making sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller expects an `ISessionState` parameter. But that's *your* interface. The infrastructure won't know how to provide it and will need an empty constructor instead.

You will need to find a way to have an empty constructor and initialize your members, especially your wrapper, somewhere. Maybe in [Initialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx)?

Comment: I think you are right that's what I think so too but how do I initialize

Answer (score 0):

To use a constructor with parameters in your controller you'd need to use a dependency injection (which is a good practice to do anyway). Personally I do have a good experience with SimpleInjector but there are many others that would do the job.